# How to drop tables using Django 2.2 migrations?

Tags: python, django, migration

Im trying to drop unused tables from the database with a single migration. The models and the references was already removed from the code, but I can't get the migration to work.

When I run the makemigration command I get something like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration)

    dependencies = [
        ('hiring', '0040_last_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Position',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='ReviewProcess',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='ReviewProcessType',
        ),
    ]
```

But if i run this migration it makes nothing, also if i run the sqlmigrate command it shows only commented lines in the sql response:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Delete model Position
--
--
-- Delete model ReviewProcess
--
--
-- Delete model ReviewProcessType
--
COMMIT;
```